# Function that takes int and converts to array inserts values backwards?

Tags: c

So I have a function that takes a number, let's just say 123 for testing purposes, and converts it to an array by inserting each digit into a place in the array.  My problem is: it does this backwards.  So 123 in this case would be printed as 321.  Any thoughts on how to change this?

```
int i = 0;

while (number) {
    array[i] = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    printf("%llu", array[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Fill the array backwards; you can determine the number of digits required by dividing a copy of `number` by `10` until it reaches `0`.

Answer (score 5):

That is because you are taking the remainder of the division between number and 10, so you are taking the last digit to insert into the first position of the array and so on.

You can make a recursive function to fill the array the way you want.  Try something like this:

```
void
fillArray (int array[], int *i, int number) {
    if (number < 10 ) {
       array[*i] = number;
       *i = *i +1;
    } else {
       fillArray (array, i, number/10);
       array[*i] = number%10;
       *i = *i +1;
    }
}
```

At the end, in i you will have the size of the array.  You should call the function like this:

```
int array[100];
int i = 0;
int n = 123;
fillArray (array,&i,n);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always reverse the array in place, seeing as you know its length when the conversion is done.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts on how to change it:  use the standard function `itoa()`.  If that is not an option, you should at least read the source code of `itoa()`.

Comment: Actually, `itoa()` is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some other way also.
Take log10(n) of the given number.

`enter code here`int nd, f, i=0;
                 nd=log10(n)
                 f=pow(10,nd);

```
            while(n)
             {
                       array[i++]=n/f;
                       n=n%f;
             }
```